# Understanding a sum with logs and prime numbers.

Tags: summation, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory, euler-product

I'm reading a proof and I don't understand this step:

> $q$ are the primes
>
> $$-\sum_q \ln \left(1-\frac{1}{q^s}\right) =  \sum_q \frac{1}{q^s} + \mathcal{O}(1)$$

Working with

$$-\ln \left(1-\frac{1}{q^s}\right) = -\ln \left(\frac{q^s-1}{q^s}\right)=\ln \left(\frac{q^s}{q^s-1}\right)=s\ln (q)+ \ln\left(\frac{1}{q^s-1}\right)$$

I've been messing with it for a bit and not seeing the connection.

Comment: $\ln(1-x) = -x-x^2/2 - x^3/3 -\cdots$ for $|x| < 1$.  The derivation uses the approximation $\ln(1 - 1/q^s)=-1/q^s$.  Summing the errors over all primes gives the $O(1)$.

Comment: Maybe the taylor expansion of ln was used?

Answer (score 1):

We have $$\begin{align}-\sum_q \ln\left(1-\frac{1}{q^s}\right)&=\sum_q\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{kq^{ks}}\\&\le\sum_q\left(-1+\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac1{q^s}\right)^k\right)\\&=\sum_q\left(-1+\frac1{1-\frac1{q^s}}\right)\\&=\sum_q\frac1{q^s-1}\\&=\sum_q \frac{1}{q^s} + \mathcal{O}(1)\end{align}$$